# Pandas updating certain values in large database but not matching dataframe size

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large database that is containing a certain number per customer per type of item. Each day there will be a lot of updates to a certain type of item of a certain customer. The database will look as following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'customer' :  ['customer1', 'customer2'], 'item1': [12, 13], 'item2' : [3, 28],'item3': [2, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'customer' :  ['customer1', 'customer2'], 'item?': ['item1', 'item1'], 'quantity' : [2, 5]})
```

```
    customer  item1  item2  item3
0  customer1     12      3      2
1  customer2     13     28      1

    customer  item?  quantity
0  customer1  item1         2
1  customer2  item1         5
```

The dataframe needs to be updated by df2, where the customer is a string and the item is also a string.

I am expecting the following dataframe:

```
    customer  item1  item2  item3
0  customer1     14      3      2
1  customer2     18     28      1
```

So essentially it is df1+df1, but this could sometimes be minus as well.

I have tried the following:

```
customerlist = df1['customer'].tolist()
for i in customerlist:
    df1.loc[df1.customer == customerlist[i]]
```

But I am already running into problems. Does someone have a function or whatever that works?

Answer (score 2):

We can use 'customer' as the `index` in both dataframes to make sure we align them correctly. Then all we do is add a reshaped version of `df2` onto `df` based on alignment on index (both rows and columns), and when the item or the customer is a mismatch we use the values from `df`:

```
df.set_index('customer').add(
    pd.pivot_table(
        df2,index='customer',columns='item?',values='quantity')
    ).fillna(df.set_index('customer')).astype(int)
```

prints:

```
           item1  item2  item3
customer                      
customer1     14      3      2
customer2     18     28      1
```

I am not sure what you mean by "sometimes be minus as well". If you mean that you want to subtract the two dataframes then use `sub` instead of `add`. If you mean there might be a minus in the values, that shouldn't affect the code because `+` and `-` will be a `-`